# Printing data from array using shorthand

Tags: arrays, reactjs, for-loop, react-admin

I am using `react-admin` framework and I am trying to print data from my `array`.
My `array` is looking like this:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FqRG4.png)

As you can see it currently has 3 indexes. Each of them stores different data. I want to print these data on to same page.

I am aware that I need to use some sort of cycle (`for`, `foreach`), but I really dont know how to implement it in `shorthand`.

This is my code, that I need to loop:

```
ID: {this.state.source[index].Id}<br></br>
AuditDate: {this.state.source[index].AuditDate}<br></br>
UserId: {this.state.source[index].UserId}<br></br>
Resource: {this.state.source[index].EntitySet}<br></br>
Entity1: {this.state.source[index].Entity1}<br></br>
Entity2: {this.state.source[index].Entity2}<br></br>
Operation: {this.state.source[index].Operation}<br></br>
EndPoint: {this.state.source[index].EndPoint}<br></br>
Changes: {this.state.source[index].Changes}<br></br>
```

Any ideas how to loop this?
Thank you in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make use of [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) to iterate over array,

```
{
this.state.source && this.state.source.length > 0 && this.state.source.map(source => {
   return <>
    <div>ID: {source.Id}</div>
    <div>AuditDate: {source.AuditDate}</div>
    <div>UserId: {source.UserId}</div>
    <div>Resource: {source.EntitySet}</div>
    <div>Entity1: {source.Entity1}</div>
    <div>Entity2: {source.Entity2}</div>
    <div>Operation: {source.Operation}</div>
    <div>EndPoint: {source.EndPoint}</div>
    <div>Changes: {source.Changes}</div>
   </>
})
}
```

Comment: Great answer, that is exactly what I needed, thank you a lot.

Answer (score 0):

```
renderSources() {
        const sources = source.map((eachSource) => {
            return (
                <div>
                    <span>`ID: ${eachSource.Id}`</span>
                    <span>`AuditDate: ${eachSource.AuditDate}`</span>
                    <span>`UserId: ${eachSource.UserId}`</span>
                    <span>`Resource: ${eachSource.EntitySet}`</span>
                    <span>`Entity1: ${eachSource.Entity1}`</span>
                    <span>`Entity2: ${eachSource.Entity2}`</span>
                    <span>`Operation: ${eachSource.Operation}`</span>
                    <span>`EndPoint: ${eachSource.EndPoint}`</span>
                    <span>`Changes: ${eachSource.Changes}`</span>
                </div>
            );
        });
        return sources;
    }

    render() {
        return (<div>{this.renderSources()}</div>);
    }
```